# Error with Clion/Cmake and Eigen

Tags: cmake, eigen

I am trying to get Eigen up and running but I am running into a roadblock.  I opened Clion and in the CMakeLists.txt tab I entered the following code. Please note I have installed Eigen with home-brew.

```
project(untitled)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

include_directories(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)

set(SRCS main.cpp)

add_executable(untitled ${SRCS})
```

I am getting the following error.

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /Users/johnmcconnell/CLionProjects/untitled
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/local/share/eigen3/cmake/Eigen3Config.cmake

  but it set Eigen3_FOUND to FALSE so package "Eigen3" is considered to be
  NOT FOUND.
```

I've never done this before and I am really at a loss, any ideas on what to do?

UPDATE:
Change in code clears the error but yields a new one.

```
fatal error: 'Eigen/Dense' file not found

project(untitled)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

include_directories(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR)

set(SRCS main.cpp)

add_executable(untitled ${SRCS})
```

Comment: Set `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/you/Eigen3/dir` in CLion.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the problem solved by @John Zwinck's answer, you have an error in your `include_directories` statement.

It should be

```
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

instead of

```
include_directories(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of the CMake module: https://github.com/RLovelett/eigen/blob/master/cmake/FindEigen3.cmake

You can see that it accepts "hints" in either `EIGEN3_ROOT` or `EIGEN3_ROOT_DIR`.  Set one of those to the base of your Eigen installation and try again:

```
EIGEN3_ROOT=blah/blah cmake ...
```

Comment: So I got it to clear the error by changing it but now I am getting an error when I run my C++ code.  "fatal error: 'Eigen/Dense' file not found." I posted the change in code above

Comment: Look for a file called Dense on your computer.  Do you have it?  Then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284473/fatal-error-eigen-dense-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: No, I do not have a file named dense. Do I need to download something else?

Comment: Well it is one of the header files of Eigen.  If you don't have it, you don't have the full Eigen development package.

Answer (score 0):

- Include the following in **CMakeLists.txt**

  ```
  set(EIGEN_DIR "C:\\Eigendir\\Eigen")
  include_directories(${EIGEN_DIR})
  add_executable(project_name main.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(project_name ${EIGEN_DIR})
  ```
- The directory in which you placed Eigen's source code must be in the include path
- `EIGEN_DIR` is set to the path where the Eigen folder is in your system
- This worked for me and do not forget the `#include <Eigen>` in the files where ever you are using Eigen... Hope this answer helps you :D

Comment: This is okay as a quick fix for private learning projects but should be avoided for anything else. Setting absolute paths in a CMakeLists.txt (or anywhere else, really) is a terrible practice.

Comment: @StefanFabian , what is the alternative?

Comment: Check out oLen's answer. This is exactly what the find_package macro is for. To provide a cross platform method of finding packages and their include paths. The reason it didn't work was simply because it wasn't used correctly.

Comment: @StefanFabian ...  I think hardcoding anywhere is a bad practice, but it's okay to do this for a personal project and there is nothing wrong in it

Comment: This is exactly what I said? Though I wouldn't say there's nothing wrong with it especially when it isn't quicker or easier than the good practice.