# OpenCV SFM Compliation

Tags: opencv, makefile, compiler-errors

I am trying to build scene_reconstruction.cpp sample from OpenCV, but I have the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/sfm.hpp:42:0,
             from scene_reconstruction.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/sfm/numeric.hpp:41:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

But I did install eigen. I tried building opencv with BUILD_EXAMPLE=ON flag, the building using make, will just terminates at 9% Built target opencv_python3

Can anyone please explain to me?

Comment: Have a look on the two posts which seem to give the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284473/fatal-error-eigen-dense-no-such-file-or-directory, https://answers.ros.org/question/44140/fatal-error-eigencore-no-such-file-or-directory/

Comment: thanks that solved the problem!

Comment: Were you able to use the sfm module with python bindings after building?