# Configure Eclipse for C++ with Eigen library

Tags: eclipse, eigen

This might be super silly question - but how do i make my eclipse identify Eigen libraries. I installed Cygwin64 (with devel option which installed Eigen under D:/Cygwin64/usr/include/Eigen3
I included Cygwin root folder in path env variable.
After this, i opened Eclipse for C++ and when i try to include Eigen `#include <Eigen/Dense>` it says `Unresolved inclusion : <Eigen/Dense>`

I googled for a while, and tried various options, but not working. How do i make my program include Eigen libraries? (like prj prop --> c++ build --> setting --> link --> misc --> adding eigen folder)
Is there a setting in eclipse where i need to specifically include it in build path?

---Update ----
I did the following

Prop --> C/C++ general --> Paths & Symbols --> GNU C++ --> added Eigen3 folder

after this, the error is changed to `fatal error : Eigen/Dense No such file or directory`

Appreciate your help!

Comment: This may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284473/fatal-error-eigen-dense-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Hi Sundararaj, thankyou. I saw this post. I wanted to resolve this within eclipse, but not using command line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you have a resolution no longer. But I have resolved this problem with the following steps.
1. proj prop -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> (GNU C++) Source Location -> Link Folder -> check "Link to folder..." -> Browse -> select eingen3 folder(eg. /usr/include/eigen3) -> OK -> Apply
2. (proj prop -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols ->) (GNU C++) Includes -> Add -> Workspace -> select "eigen3" -> OK -> Apply
3. Click OK and close the Properties window.

The progress bar is moving, and Analyzing is finished, then you can see green terms related Eigen.

I hope this makes you help.