# fatal error: 'Eigen/Dense' file not found

Tags: python, c++

I am an Ultra Linux newbie, and I am trying to install this [program](https://github.com/xbpeng/DeepMimic) and when I try to build the python wrapper I'd get this

```
~/Downloads/DeepMimic-master/DeepMimicCore$ make python
clang++ -c -g -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -fPIC  -I./ -I../../libraries/eigen -I../../libraries/bullet3/src -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/lib/ -lpython3.6m  -o objs/Main.o Main.cpp
clang: warning: -lpython3.6m: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
In file included from Main.cpp:3:
In file included from ./DeepMimicCore.h:3:
In file included from ./util/ArgParser.h:6:
./util/MathUtil.h:5:10: fatal error: 'Eigen/Dense' file not found
#include "Eigen/Dense"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a dependency, Eigen, which is listed under 'Dependencies' in the DeepMimic readme.

I see this problem has been encountered before:
[fatal error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284473/fatal-error-eigen-dense-no-such-file-or-directory?rq=1)

Comment: well i am sure that i have followed the installation instructions, is there a way to check?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like that program depends on Eigen. Try download Eigen and putting it in the appropriate directory.

Eigen is a template library, so you just have to download it, unzip it, and copy the folder called Eigen inside of the directory of the program.

[Eigen website](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)